# How to adjust the space between columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to narrow the space between the left part and right part of this web page, it's collapsing, but I didn't find it in the style sheet.

web page: http://Megamadz.com the **gap** is too wide between the left: Ever wonder with a graph  and the right side: platform...

Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: The gap is composed of 15px padding on both the left and right elements, caused by the bootstrap column styling.

Comment: What about working on the margin-left/right of the different divs?

Comment: Did you wrap your .row's within a .container ?

Answer (score 1):

the bootstrap framework is adding the padding for you (on larger sized screens).  The easiest thing to do would be to add some extra classes to the left and right columns (which are now col-lg-9 and col-lg-3), then style those so:

```
.left { padding-right: 0px }
.right { padding-left: 0px }
```

if you can't control the html to add the classes to the elements, you could try this rather nasty css selector:

```
.middle > .row > .col-lg-9 { padding-left: 0px }
.middle > .row > .col-lg-3 { padding-right: 0px }
```

or

```
.middle > .row > div:first-child { }
.middle > .row > div:last-child { }
```

but of course those will be quite fragile if you make any other changes to the structure of the html, so I wouldn't recommend it. :)

Also, you may want to add additional media queries so that the style you want to apply is only effective for larger screens, otherwise you'll affect the responsive layout on small screens.

Alternatively you can customize the entire bootstrap theme to have narrower gutters, etc, but that would affect everything on the site  http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the `padding-right` and `padding-left` attributes of the BootStrap columns.

[Allan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29638409/how-to-adjust-the-space-between-columns/29638572#29638572) gives you a few ways to do it, but you can also use [in-line styles](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) to change it for those particular elements without affecting the rest of your site.

In-line styling for the left div:

```
<div class="col-lg-9" style="padding-right: 5px;">
    <div class="mainSec">...</div>
    ...
</div>
```

In-line styling for the right div:

```
<div class="col-lg-3" style="padding-left: 5px;">
    <div class="panel panel-success">...</div>
    ...
</div>
```

These styles would have [this result](http://puu.sh/hec4K/aeb75563c8.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

Both .container and .col-xx-xx have padding and margin.  Always double check parent elements when this sort of thing happens.